# Function switch recursion with possibility of an endless loop

Tags: php, class, function, loops, recursion

I did not find this type of scenario in stackoverflow and google searches.

I have run into a problem with the logic in my code I have written. The problem is on case 18 in the rollGiftsandLegacies function below:

```
class char
{
    private function d4() { $RNG = mt_rand(1,4); return $RNG; }
    // etc.

    public function recursiveArrayShrink($array) {
        array_walk_recursive($array, function($v, $k, $res) { $res[] = $v; }, $res);
        return $res;
    }
    private function rollCulture($dice) {
        switch($dice) {
            case 1: // For this culture, we have a 1-3 different types of rewards
                for ($i = 1; $i <= $this->d3(); $i++) {
                    $GiftsAndLegacies[$i] = $this->rollGiftsandLegacies($this->d20());
                }
                $results = $this->recursiveArrayShrink($GiftsAndLegacies);
                $this->character['culture']['benefits'] = $results;
            break;
        }
    }
    private function rollGiftsandLegacies($dice) {
        switch($dice) {
            case 1: // A Weapon
                switch($this->d10()) {
                    case 1: $gifts[] = "Gemmed dagger."; break;
                    case 2: $gifts[] = "Gemmed sword."; break;
                    case 3: $gifts[] = "Plain sword."; break;
                    case 4: $gifts[] = "A mace."; break;
                    case 5: $gifts[] = "Gemmed spear."; break;
                    case 6: $gifts[] = "Well-made short or long bow."; break;
                    case 7: $gifts[] = "Gemmed battle-axe."; break;
                    case 8: $gifts[] = "Any type of crossbow."; break;
                    case 9: $gifts[] = "Exotic weapon. GM Only"; break;
                    // Simple re-roll example: works!
                    case 10: 
                        for($i = 1; $i <= $this->d4(); $i++) {
                            $gifts[] = $this->rollGiftsandLegacies($dice = 16);
                        }
                    break;
                }
            break;
            case 2: $gift = "A tapestry."; break;
            case 18: // SEALED TRUNK: 60% chance that it contains 2-4 additional items on this table.
                if($this->d100() <= 60) {
                    $gifts[] = "A sealed trunk with contents:";
                    $this->GiftsAndLegaciesSealedTrunk = $this->d3() + 1;
                    for($i = 1; $i <= $this->GiftsAndLegaciesSealedTrunk; $i++) {
                        $roll = $this->d20();
                        $item = $this->recursiveArrayShrink($this->rollGiftsandLegacies($roll));
                        $item[0] = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i>". $item[0];
                        $item[0] .= "</i>";
                        $gifts[] = $item;
                    }
                } else {
                    $gifts[] = "A sealed trunk that is empty.";
                }
            break;
        }
        return $gifts[];
    }
}
```

I get it to display correctly, but I feel I could do this so much better...

the array, and the foreach to actually loop through the results looks like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => A sealed chest with contents:
    [1] =>     A musical instrument.
    [2] =>     The characters true (and colorful) family history.
    [3] =>     Gemmed dagger.
    [4] =>     A sealed trunk with contents:
    [5] =>     Gemmed sword.
    [6] =>     A map.
    [7] =>     A sealed trunk with contents:
    [8] =>     Plain sword.
)
if(isset($c['culture']['benefits'])) {
    foreach($c['culture']['benefits'] as $benefit) {
        print("".$benefit."<br>");
    }
}
```

If I roll two sealed trunks (or more infinitely) with things inside it, it looks like this:

A sealed trunk with contents:

> *A musical instrument.*
>   *The characters true (and colorful) family history.*
>   *Gemmed dagger.*
>   *A sealed trunk with contents:*
>   *Gemmed sword.*
>   *A map.*
>   *A sealed trunk with contents:*
>   *Plain sword.*

I want it to look like:

A sealed trunk with contents:

> *A musical instrument.*
> *The characters true (and colorful) family history.*
> *Gemmed dagger.*

A sealed trunk with contents:

> *Gemmed sword.*
> *A map.*

A sealed trunk with contents:

> *Plain sword.*

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is it necessary to play D&D to understand that question or something?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.. that 1st reward in the FOR loop @ the cultureRoll function generates d4 more items in that list from rollRewards. How would I call this and re-iterate through that loop to include the d4 more items? (and yes, if it rolls a 1 and then another 10, d4 MORE items!! is very unclear on what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: I don't think you need to play D&D to understand it, but it certainly helps!

Comment: @netcoder, not really, to answer your question its optional.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to use a `$cultureRewards` variable.

Set it to the correct value at the start, and have a loop:

```
while ($cultureRewards > 0) {
    # roll dice
    $cultureRewards--;

    if ($dice == 1) {
        $cultureRewards += d3();
    }
}
```

Editted to add:

It's not quite as easy as I first thought; you'd have to pass `$cultureRewards` into `rollRewards` as a parameter, as that's where you're looking to see if you get extra dice rolls, right?

Comment: Yeah pretty much. If you roll a 1 in rollRewards, then you're brought to a subtable, which is now a d10. If you roll a 10 on that subtable, you get an additional d4 items on that same subtable. :) your answer is helpful atleast... ill take some more crackin' at it

Comment: So 1 on that subtable is 'An extra D4 rolls on this table'? Is that right? Can you tweak your code so that the rewards are returned as an array, instead of as a string? Because then it's all very simple!

Comment: That looks like a much more elegant way of doing it than I was thinking - yay for recursion!